# Reading Int Values from file, all in one line

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, filesystems

Im here because I have weird problem. I wanted to read some int values from txt file. All of them are in one line. To do that simple task I created very simple node.js code:

```
const readValues = fs.createReadStream(('txt\\' + file[0]));
readValues.setEncoding();                  //It's because I want String here
readValues.on('data', (chunk) => {
    chunk = chunk.trim();
    chunk.split(' ').forEach(value => {
        values.push(parseInt(value, 10));
    });
});
```

[Then Im getting this warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9ZJ9.jpg)

But when I add console.log to show those values in console:

```
const readValues = fs.createReadStream(('txt\\' + file[0]));
readValues.setEncoding();                  //It's because I want String here
readValues.on('data', (chunk) => {
    chunk = chunk.trim();
    chunk.split(' ').forEach(value => {
        console.log(value);    // here
        values.push(parseInt(value, 10));
    });
});
```

Then all those values are shown in the console and above warning dosen't here.
I tested also readFileSync:

```
const readValues = fs.readFileSync(('txt//' + file[0]), 'utf8').trim();
readValues.split(' ').forEach(value => {
    values.push(parseInt(value, 10));
});
//console.log(values);
```

But the outcome is reversed - Im getting that error when I display those values, but when I don't display that, I don't get it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/btLOE.jpg
This is happening in LTS version of node and in 11.11.0. I ran out of ideas and I didn't found any solution. Maybe someone from u know where do I made some mistake ?? I would be grateful for some help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I initialized Arrays in wrong way.

I used this way:

```
const values = Array.prototype;
```

And It should be in this way:

```
const values = new Array();
```

Alright, my fault. I trolled myself because I wanted to create perfect code at first step. And Im not perfect person. Im sorry for bother you. Im leave here the answer for the other ppl.